# Html2canvas cannot render map in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OL3 and the last version of Html2Canvas (1.0.0-rc.5). When I try to make a PNG screenshot of the div that embed the map it seems that the map itself is blank. Also the feature, that are located on my map, are not drawn on the PNG produced by Html2Canvas.

```
html2canvas($('#mapDiv')[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var html = '<html><head><title>' + textHead + '</title></head>';
        html += '<body style="width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;"';
        html += ' onload="window.focus(); window.print(); window.close()">';
        html += '<img src="' + img + '" width="800" /></body></html>';
        var w = window.open();
        w.document.open();
        w.document.write(html);
        w.document.close();
    });
```

[image: Blank map and disappeared features]

Comment: That happens if your map canvas is tainted.  You may need to specify `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` in tile and image layer sources.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Mike , I found the same solution on a previous question but in my case also the features are invisible, so it is not just related on tiles (I used also the 'anonymous' on crossOrigin).

Comment: @TomazicM, no, nothing on the console.

Comment: If you are using OpenLayers 3/4/5 all layers are rendered to a single canvas, if any layer taints it html2canvas would ignore the canvas (there would be no console errors) and export no layers.  OpenLayers 6 usually uses one canvas per layer - if one is tainted some layers may be exported while others are not.

Comment: @Mike, your first answer solved the problem. Now, also the features are shown on the PNG. Thank you.  
Please, write that as an answer and I will give you the "check" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [Mike](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102658/mike) answered the question:

> That happens if your map canvas is tainted. You may need to specify
> crossOrigin: 'anonymous' in tile and image layer sources.

Now, also the features are shown on the PNG image.